# Ajax Push - what to consider?

Tags: ajax, comet, ajax-push

I'm looking into "Comet", "Ajax Push" or "Reverse Ajax" and have found APE: http://www.ape-project.org. It seems very promising. Any one with experience with this? Any pros and cons I should know about?

Also, are there any other engines I should be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to be using WebSockets or Comet.

If you want to self-host there are the following options:

- http://faye.jcoglan.com/
- http://socket.io/
- Jetty: http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/jetty_websocket_server
- http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/
- Ruby EventMachine WebSocket server: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket
- Meteor: http://meteorserver.org/
- GlassFish: http://glassfish.java.net/
- ErlyComet: http://code.google.com/p/erlycomet/
- cometD: http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/

If you don't want to host the real-time infrastructure then you could use a hosted service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com) who I work for.

Comment: your service looks interesting. Will be looking into it. Any comments about APE?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - I've not had a chance to play with the APE technology. I do like the Gorillas at the top of the website though :) One good thing from a quick skim of their docs is that they do have a [WebSocket transport](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:Use_different_transport_method_%28JSONP,_XHRStreaming%29#WebSocket) option which means that the most efficient transport mechanism is supported. Sorry I can't provide you with more specific help with that part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer, but APE has very little documentation for 1.  See this page http://www.nulldevice.de/2010/09/ape-ajax-push-engine/